# Why integer column data returns by ascii encoding?

Tags: sql, postgresql, erlang, postgres-xl

I am moving the database from postgres to postgres-xl. 
The client driver the `erlang`'s `epgsql`:

The table schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table1 (id integer primary key, value text);
```

test data:

```
INSERT INTO test_table1 (id, value) VALUES (3001, '3001 number');
```

For sql query,  The extended query protocol is used, parsing the sql command in the client side.

But the returned data is as follows:

```
 <<0,0,0,4,51,48,48,49,0,0,0,11,51,48,48,49,32,110,117,109,98,101,114>>
```

for integer `3001`, The data is encoded as ascii coded by `51,48,48,49`, it is not expected as `<<0,0,0b,b9>>`. How to control it by client-side parameter or by server-side parameter?

Comment: I am no SQL expert but does it have anything to do with HOW you have defined the field in the db?

Comment: I have read a little about the postgres-xl front-backend protocol, which is not same as postgres protocol.  The protocol has 2 mode, simple mode and extended mode. For simple mode data always to be sent by text format. For extended mode, it combine 3 steps (parse, bind, execute), Only bind done, the data will be returned by binary format. I will make some experiment to make it more clear.

Comment: The problem has been solved. The erlang's driver epgsql doesn't work well with postgres-xl. I have modified the epgsql's source code to solve the problem.